# Is Plants vs Zombies 2 available for tablets only?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies-2

I've got an Android phone (Samsung Galaxy S3). Does Plants vs Zombies 2 support phones too, or only tablets?

The game is released for Android in China but not on Play Store, so I don't know how to check that.

Comment: Why don't you download it and find out? The [APK file is available on the Chinese app store.](http://as.baidu.com/a/item?docid=4249303) If you want to know if the future Play Store international version of the game will be compatible, we can't help you with that since that isn't available yet (though in all likelihood the answer will be yes, it will support smartphones)

Comment: If the Chinese APK works for phones, then it's extremely likely that the future Play Store version will. If I just downloaded to find out, that would not help anyone else. If this question gets an answer, whether it's from me or someone else, then people can simply find the answer through here instead of testing themselves.

Comment: I'm really not sure how useful such an answer will be given that the Play store already does compatibility checking before it allows you to download an app

Answer (score 2):

Plants vs Zombies 2 was exclusively for iPad, iPhone and iPod touch. source: [About text](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gbcBYs0ljI0)

It is now available for Android in China through [Baidu’s AppSearch Android market](http://as.baidu.com/a/item?docid=4249303), It requires Android 2.3+ so it will work on phones also since tablets have a minimum of version 3.0. [source](http://androidcommunity.com/plants-vs-zombies-2-for-android-lands-in-china-20130912/)

And is set to release on android for the rest of the world Fall 2013. [source](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10151687801023214)

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plants_vs._Zombies_2:_It's_About_Time) it is released on Android in China, and will be released internationally later this fall.

Comment: @3ventic updated the answer to reflect the information you provided

Comment: Is it available for tablets only in China, or for phones too?

Comment: It requires Android 2.3+ and tablets have a minimum of Android 3.0 so it will work on phones also.